# Finding the moment generating function of a random variable $Z$.

Tags: probability, statistics, moment-generating-functions

Given the m.g.f $M_x=\exp(3t+8t^2)$ of a continuous random variable $X$, find an m.g.f of the random variable $z=0.5(x-3)$, and use to find the mean and variance of $z$

My working:

We know that $\mu=(M_xt)', t=0$ upon doing this, I got $\mu=3$ and $E(x^2)=(M_xt)'', t=0$ and got $E(x^2)=25$.

And because $Var(x)=25-(3)^2=16$.

Am I on the right track? How do I find the mean and variance of $z$? Do I simply just put the values of that I obtained from above?

Comment: Your $X$ has normal distribution. See any textbook on probability (or Wikipedia) to see how you can identify the variance and the mean from the moment generating function. Which you seem to have done already. Now, since $Z$ is also normal (identify the mean and the variance) then you can get the desired function easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that the MGF of a random variable $X$ is given by $$M_X(t) = \operatorname{E}[e^{tX}].$$  Thus, if $Z = \frac{1}{2}(X-3)$, then the MGF of $Z$ is given by $$M_Z(t) = \operatorname{E}[e^{tZ}] = \operatorname{E}[e^{t(X-3)/2}] = \operatorname{E}[e^{tX/2} e^{-3t/2}] = \operatorname{E}[e^{(t/2)X}] \operatorname{E}[e^{-3t/2}] = M_X(t/2) e^{-3t/2}.$$  Now substituting $$M_X(t) = e^{3t+8t^2},$$ being careful to first replace $t$ with $t/2$, we now have the MGF of $Z$.  Then we calculate $$\operatorname{E}[Z] = M_Z'(0), \quad \operatorname{Var}[Z] = M_Z''(0)$$ using the function we just obtained, the calculation of which I have left to you as an exercise.

Comment: I see
It makes more sense now

Thank you so much!